# Spring framework and spring integration compatibility

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm looking for some material (list/table/article) covering spring framework and spring integration compatibility. As far as I know same major version work together perfectly, but am  I forced to use the same versions? Can I upgrade spring framework to version 4 and stay with spring integration version 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer just from the first pages of [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html)

Here I show you the manual of the latest Spring Integration 3.0 version.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering how could I miss those paragraphs of documentation. But I still can't find information about spring integration 2.2.x compatibility. Spring documentation only says that integration 2.2.x is compatible with spring framework 3.0.x and maven dependencies tell that integration 2.2.6 is compatible with framework 3.1.3.

Comment: That was our fault for Docs as it was for a long time ago already. The SI 2.2 is compatible with all Spring 3.x versions.